# Infinite number of Lie groups with the same lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there a finite dimensional Lie algebra L such that there are infinite number of non isomorphic compact connected lie groups which Lie algebras  are isomorphic to L?

Comment: $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{R})$

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to edit the question (without any mention of the edit), especially after the answer appeared.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To develop Yves' comment : let $G$ be the simply connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$; it contains a central subgroup $Z\cong \mathbb{Z}$ such that $G/Z\cong \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. Now put $G_n:=G/nZ$ for $n\geq 1$. An isomorphism  $G_p\rightarrow G_q$ lifts to an isomorphism $G\rightarrow G$ which must map $pZ$ into $qZ$; this implies $p=q$, thus all these groups are non-isomorphic.

Comment: thank you very much  for the answer. What about if we require  that all groups are compact, as I revised the question in this new version?

Comment: Then the answer is negative. A compact Lie group admits a finite covering $T\times S$, with $T$ a torus and $S$ semi-simple, and these have only a finite number of non-isomorphic quotients.